# Redshift access denied automatically in REDSHIFT

Tags: amazon-redshift, aginity

`grant usage on schema apps to group group_name;`

`grant SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN schema apps to group group_name;`

`alter default privileges in schema apps grant select on tables to group group_name;`

Comments used by gave access to group

I created the user or group in redshift. Initially, they have a access to the tables. When the table recreates the access automatically declined. Can anyone help to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I can help.  The users need to have default ACLs set which give all tables that user creates a set of grants.  See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html

The creator of the object needs to grant to others but this can be done automatically by setting their default pricileges.

Hope this helps